# Dropping partitions in Hive

Tags: hive, partition

Hi All the table is partitioned on column 1 and column 2 both being INT types,I am using the following command to drop the partition,column1 is equal to null or **HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION**

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(column1=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__,column2=101);
```

but i am getting the following error :missing \' at ',' near ''

when i do:

**`show partitions Table_Name`** (this is how the partition to be dropped looks)

Output:

```
column1=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__/column2=101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers guys appreciate it ..actually figured out the problem

`ALTER TABLE Table_Name DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(column1<1,column2=101);`

as column1 had a null value entry which i wanted to remove which was **HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION** or (null) so using conditions <1 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting **HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION** in quotes

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name DROP IF EXISTS 
PARTITION(column1='__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__',column2=101);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly drop the partition on column2.

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(column2=101);
```